# Javascript number game not showing output

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, event-listener

I have been trying to make a game in Javascript where the browser generates 2 random numbers and an operand by clicking a button and the user has to type in the answer of the displayed calculation in an input area. If the answer is correct, the browser displays an alert saying that it is correct. Everything works fine, the numbers and operands are getting displayed, the user is able to type in his answer, but I am not getting any alert from the browser.

Here is the HTML and Javascript code (I haven't applied any style to it yet).

```js
function displayOperation() {
    let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    let operandArr = ["+", "-", "*"];
    let randomOperand = operandArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * operandArr.length)];
    document.getElementById("number_one").innerHTML = num1;
    document.getElementById("number_two").innerHTML = num2;
    document.getElementById("operand_type").innerHTML = randomOperand;
    switch (randomOperand) {
        case "+":
            add();
            break;
        case "-":
            subtract();
            break;
        case "*":
            multiply();
            break;
    }

    function add() {
        let res = num1 + num2;
        let userAnswer = document.getElementById("text_Area").value;
        document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (userAnswer === res) {
                alert("correct!");
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
    }

    function subtract() {
        let res = num1 - num2;
        let userAnswer = document.getElementById("text_Area").value;
        document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (userAnswer === res) {
                alert("correct!");
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
    }

    function multiply() {
        let res = num1 * num2;
        let userAnswer = document.getElementById("text_Area").value;
        document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (userAnswer === res) {
                alert("correct!");
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
    }
}

document.getElementById("reload").addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayOperation();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Number Game</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div id="number_one">

</div>
<div id="operand_type">

</div>
<div id="number_two">

</div>
<div id="text_Area">
    <label for="answer">
        <input type="number" id="answer">
    </label>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
    <button type="button" id="reload">Load</button>
</div>
<div id="result">

</div>
<script src="index.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Some input would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had multiple issues in your code. The input field for the answer has the id `answer` not `text_Area`. you were defining the functions for add, multiply and substract in the wrong scope. and you were using `===` for the check but `.value` returns a string and `num1 + num2` (for example) returns a integer, so the check would always be wrong. If you have questions about my changes to your code, I'm happy to help.

```js
var operandArr = ["+", "-", "*"];
var num1;
var num2;
var randomOperand;

function displayOperation() {
    num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    randomOperand = operandArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * operandArr.length)];
    document.getElementById("number_one").innerHTML = num1;
    document.getElementById("number_two").innerHTML = num2;
    document.getElementById("operand_type").innerHTML = randomOperand;
}

document.getElementById("reload").addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayOperation();
});

function calculate() {
  switch (randomOperand) {
    case "+":
        add()
        break;
    case "-":
        subtract()
        break;
    case "*":
        multiply()
        break;
  }
}

function add() {
    let res = num1 + num2;
    let userAnswer = document.getElementById("answer").value;
    if (parseInt(userAnswer) === res) {
        alert("correct!");
        window.location.reload();
    }
}

function subtract() {
    let res = num1 - num2;
    let userAnswer = document.getElementById("answer").value;
    if (parseInt(userAnswer) === res) {
        alert("correct!");
        window.location.reload();
    }
}

function multiply() {
    let res = num1 * num2;
    let userAnswer = document.getElementById("answer").value;
    if (parseInt(userAnswer) === res) {
        alert("correct!");
        window.location.reload();
    }
}

document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", function () {
    calculate();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Number Game</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div id="number_one">

</div>
<div id="operand_type">

</div>
<div id="number_two">

</div>
<div id="text_Area">
    <label for="answer">
        <input type="number" id="answer">
    </label>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
    <button type="button" id="reload">Load</button>
</div>
<div id="result">

</div>
<script src="index.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @AdwaitKulkarni. Glad I could help. Would you mind choosing my answer for your question?

Comment: Sure! This looks a lot tidier and I understood where I was going wrong too! Thanks again!

Comment: Also, could you let me know whether the logic part of my code was right? I am beginning to develop a few projects on my own and would love some feedback!

Comment: You were pretty near. Your logic was ok but you have to pay attention on scopes. Variables defined in an function are only available in its body. Thats why i extracted them to the "root-scope". You also need to be careful with `addEventListener` because those will stack. But overall a pretty good approach. Nice done!

Answer (score 1):

You can extract computation into another function and do required computation with Function()

```js
function displayOperation() {
    let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    let operandArr = ["+", "-", "*"];
    let randomOperand = operandArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * operandArr.length)];
    document.getElementById("number_one").innerHTML = num1;
    document.getElementById("number_two").innerHTML = num2;
    document.getElementById("operand_type").innerHTML = randomOperand;
}

document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", function () {
  let num1 = document.getElementById("number_one").innerHTML;
    let num2 = document.getElementById("number_two").innerHTML;
    let randomOperand = document.getElementById("operand_type").innerHTML;
let userAnswer = document.getElementById("answer").value;
        let res = Function(`'use strict'; return (${num1 + randomOperand +num2})`)() ;
        console.log(res)
            if (parseInt(userAnswer) === res) {
                alert("correct!");
                window.location.reload();
            } else {
            console.log('huuu')
            }
        });
document.getElementById("reload").addEventListener("click", displayOperation);
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Number Game</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div id="number_one">

</div>
<div id="operand_type">

</div>
<div id="number_two">

</div>
<div id="text_Area">
    <label for="answer">
        <input type="number" id="answer">
    </label>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
    <button type="button" id="reload">Load</button>
</div>
<div id="result">

</div>
<script src="index.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I am relatively new to JavaScript, so I don't have an idea about Function but I will surely check this out!